# Getting implicit conversion operator in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to get symbol for implicit conversion operator in roslyn, but not getting it for code:

```
int? i;
i = 1;
```

I was expecting symbol for:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value)
{
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}
```

Here my test code:

```
internal class Walker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public SemanticModel Model { get; set; }

    public override void VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        var o = (IAssignmentExpression)Model.GetOperation(node);
        if (o.Value.Kind == OperationKind.ConversionExpression)
        {
            var c = (IConversionExpression)o.Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"{(c.IsExplicit ? "explicit" : "implicit")} conversion from {c.Operand.ConstantValue.Value} via {(c.UsesOperatorMethod ? c.OperatorMethod.ToString() : "?")}");
        }
        base.VisitAssignmentExpression(node);
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int? i;
        i = 1;
    }
}");
        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(null, new[] { tree }, new[] { mscorlib });
        var walker = new Walker { Model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree) };
        walker.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
    }
}
```

And output is:

```
implicit conversion from 1 via ?
```

Am I doing something wrong or it is a bug in roslyn?

Project on github - https://github.com/isanych/so-39396441

Comment: The compiler will directly inject a constructor call, some of these built in operators are not handled as operators, the compiler has intimate knowledge about them.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen, yes, I see only constructor call in IL, could I get operation for it then? I'm trying to get actual expression/statements from code and syntax nodes are not always good in cases when operations are very different from syntax - like using properties, indexers and especially linq. I was hoping that operations will help me to avoid workarounds, as roslyn should have this information anyway.

Comment: There is no conversion operator in the compiled code, that is the issue here. The compiler has just compiled this into a direct construction instead.

Comment: I understand that there is no call to conversion operator in IL code, but I don't understand logic behind conversion expression without symbol. I would expect either conversion expression with symbol or operation for constructor call. Such implementation require workaround based on current compiler behavior, which does not look nice.

Comment: Instead of getting the Operation, have you tried [GetConversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpextensions.getconversion?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.1.0#microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-csharpextensions-getconversion(microsoft-codeanalysis-semanticmodel-microsoft-codeanalysis-syntaxnode-system-threading-cancellationtoken))?